# How to use LIKE clause with IN caluse in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I want to use LIKE clause and IN clause together.
e.g: Currently my query is -

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   [USER_DETAILS] 
WHERE 
   [NAME] LIKE 'Dev%' OR 
   [NAME] LIKE 'Deb%' OR 
   ......
   ......
```

How can i use IN clause to achieve this?
Can someone please help? :)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You could look into Full Text Search. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441981/Full-Text-Search-on-SQL-2000-Part-1.htm for instance. It doesn't answer your question, but may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the parameter values in a table, then use a single `JOIN` condition e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [USER_DETAILS] AS U1
       INNER JOIN Params AS P1
          ON U1.[NAME] LIKE P1.param + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with NullUserException - there is no such syntax.
"In" is "syntax sugar" for predicate equal. There is no analog for other operations like >, <, so you should use OR.