# how to use like and in query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a combination of “LIKE” and “IN” in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

can we use like and in condition in same query like this

```
    select inticap(last_name),length(last_name) from employees
    where last_name in(like '%J%',like '%A%',like '%M%');

OR 

  select inticap(last_name),length(last_name) from employees
where last_name like in( '%J%', '%A%',l'%M%');
```

i know it wont work . here i want to display initial letter of last name capital  and the length of last name and i want to display name with alphabets 'A' ,'J'and 'M'. please help me

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335359/is-it-possible-to-use-like-and-in-for-a-where-statment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747996/in-sql-server-how-do-i-search-for-multiple-values-in-a-column-where-i-need-to-u/10748091#10748091 and many others

Comment: No it won't work, You can use OR in query like  last_name like '%J%' OR like '%A%'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned, you cannot directly combine `LIKE` and `IN` as you would prefer.

Here's one kludgy option:

```
SELECT INITCAP(last_name)
,      LENGTH(last_name)
FROM   employees
WHERE  +1 IN (SIGN(INSTR(last_name,'J'))
          ,   SIGN(INSTR(last_name,'A'))
          ,   SIGN(INSTR(last_name,'M')))
```

Or, if you're on at least 10g, you can use regular expressions:

```
SELECT INITCAP(last_name)
,      LENGTH(last_name)
FROM   employees
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(last_name,'(J|A|M)')
```

...but regular expressions in general are more CPU-intensive than your garden-variety SQL functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
 select inticap(last_name),length(last_name) from employees
where last_name like '%J%' OR last_name like '%A%' OR last_name '%M%';
```

Comment: hi i know it will work but i want to write query with in and like

Comment: U can look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350106/how-to-use-like-clause-with-in-caluse-in-sql-server

Comment: With respect to the link in the previous comment: instead of creating a table you could also use a piplined function and add your 'like' conditions programmaticly to a PL/SQL table.